# Copy multiple files to multiple folders using FileDialog in Access vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am looking for a way to copy multiple files from a single folder and copy this grouping of files to multiple folders using FileDialog in Access vba. Below is what I have so far - the problem with this code is that I can only copy multiple files from a single folder to another single folder. Can anyone help with this:

```
Public Function CopyFilesToFolders()

On Error GoTo Err_Copy

Dim sourcefiles As String
Dim destination As String
Dim source As String

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

        .Title = "Select a folder that contains the desired files to copy."

        If .Show = -1 Then source = .SelectedItems(1)
        If Len(source) = 0 Then Exit Function
        .AllowMultiSelect = True

        .Title = "Select a folder location to copy the files."

        If .Show = -1 Then destination = .SelectedItems(1)
        If Len(destination) = 0 Then Exit Function

    End With

sourcefiles = Dir$(source & "\*.*")

    Do While Len(sourcefiles) > 0

        FileCopy (source & "\" & sourcefiles), (destination & "\" & sourcefiles)

        sourcefiles = Dir$

    Loop

Exit_Copy:

    Exit Function

Err_Copy:
    CopyFilesToFolders = True
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Exit_Copy

MsgBox "Task Complete!"

End Function
```

Thank you,
Al

Comment: Ask the user for additional destination folders?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I don't see a *specific* question.  You can [edit] your post - but first, please check the [tour] as well as "[help/on-topic]" and also "[ask]". Also there's good tips [here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question) and "[mcve]".

Comment: The part where you ask the user for a destination folder, just move it into your loop and it should work.

Comment: Thanks Foxfire however moving the part where the user is asked for a destination folder in the loop only allows the user to choose 1 destination folder at a time. I need the copied source files to be copied to all subfolders in the destination folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want the function to automatically detect all the subfolders and copy the selected files to them? You can use FileSystemObject to detect all the subfolders, then copy the files to them. See this modified function:

```
Public Function CopyFilesToFolders()

On Error GoTo Exit_Copy

Dim sourcefiles As String
Dim destination As String
Dim source As String

Dim FileSystem As Object

Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

        .Title = "Select a folder that contains the desired files to copy."

        If .Show = -1 Then source = .SelectedItems(1)
        If Len(source) = 0 Then Exit Function
        .AllowMultiSelect = True

        .Title = "Select a folder location to copy the files."

        If .Show = -1 Then destination = .SelectedItems(1)

        If Len(destination) = 0 Then Exit Function


    End With

sourcefiles = Dir$(source & "\*.*")

Dim SubFolder

    Do While Len(sourcefiles) > 0

        For Each SubFolder In FileSystem.GetFolder(destination).SubFolders
            FileCopy (source & "\" & sourcefiles), (SubFolder.path & "\" & sourcefiles)
        Next

        sourcefiles = Dir$

    Loop

Exit_Copy:

    Exit Function

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you jshort - I'll give your modified function a try and let you know if it gives the expected results.

Comment: Hello jshort - You're solution worked perfectly, thank you! In fact I have 3 scenarios that I am trying to develop. Should I post the next 2 here or would it be better to open a new post?

Comment: Hello jshort - I went ahead and posted a new question for a second scenario. Just to let you know, I have changed my username to TechOffAl.

Comment: @TechOffAl glad it worked for you. Please check the question as answered and upvote if my answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, for changing the topic a bit, but I think int would be a lot easier to do this in Excel, rather than in Access.  See the example below.

```
Sub sbCopyingAFile()

'Declare Variables
Dim FSO
Dim sFile As String
Dim sSFolder As String
Dim sDFolder As String

'This is Your File Name which you want to Copy
sFile = "Sample.xls"

'Change to match the source folder path
sSFolder = "C:\Temp\"

'Change to match the destination folder path
sDFolder = "D:\Job\"

'Create Object
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Checking If File Is Located in the Source Folder
If Not FSO.FileExists(sSFolder & sFile) Then
    MsgBox "Specified File Not Found", vbInformation, "Not Found"

'Copying If the Same File is Not Located in the Destination Folder
ElseIf Not FSO.FileExists(sDFolder & sFile) Then
    FSO.CopyFile (sSFolder & sFile), sDFolder, True
    MsgBox "Specified File Copied Successfully", vbInformation, "Done!"
Else
    MsgBox "Specified File Already Exists In The Destination Folder", vbExclamation, "File Already Exists"
End If

End Sub
```

Now, if you want to dynamically list the files in a folder, each file path in an individual cell, and then specify exactly which files to copy from one folder to another, that is definitely doable.  First, try the sample code above, and give me feedback for future enhancements.

Comment: Thank you ryguy72 for your suggestion! I would prefer to use Access because this function will be added to an existing database program and I do need the FileDialog function so that the user can select the source and destination folders.